# Mysql query which would execute itself in 1 minute

Tags: php, mysql

I want that certain mysql query would be executed in 1 minute after `mysql_query()` function executes in the php file. Is it possible to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to do this for security reasons and avoid being flooded by requests? This approach is not a good security measure. Better to check time against the requesting IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use MySQL's SLEEP().

```
SELECT SLEEP(60), yourColumns from yourTable
```

or just

```
SELECT SLEEP(60); yourOtherQuery
```

But note your script will be running for 60 seconds because by default, your php will wait for the result. If you don't want this, you should fork a new process so the php process can finish and return data to the user.

#### Edit: you said you don't want people to wait

If you don't want people to wait, you should fork a new process, or signal a running process (daemon) to execute your query.

Comment: No, I don't want that people would wait.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side you could stop execution for a minute with `sleep(60)` but I don´t know if that is a possibility.

On the client side you could set a javascript timeout and use ajax to execute your second query.

I would recommend the second option as your browser might time-out if it doesn't hear anything from the server for a minute. How to avoid that, depends on your server configuration.